# How to disable these VSCode tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I am typing, these tooltips show up. Is there a way to disable them?

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one missing setting to disable some tooltips which gives more information.

Go to Settings in VSCode and search for `Hover` you can disable that one to finish with the hover popups forever.

Comment: The editor.hover.enabled setting does not prevent the parameter/argument overlay shown above from appearing.

The setting to disable the popup the OP describes is editor.parameterHints.enabled.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways to customize the IntelliSense in VSCode. I believe the one in your picture is a *parameter hint*. You can go to *File → Preferences → Settings* and search for `"parameterHints"`.

Here are some others you can tweak:

```js
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": true,

// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,

// Enable parameter hints
"editor.parameterHints": true
```

More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

Comment: But, this does not get rid of the info popups.